# Having trouble with conditionals

Tags: ruby, math, conditional-statements

I'm trying to define a method that returns "fizz" when the integer is divisible by 3, "buzz" when is divisible by 5 and "fuzzbuzz" when the number is divisible by both. I know 15 is divisible by both, however I don't know what I'm inputting wrong in my code. Thank you.

```
def fizzbuzz(int)
  if int % 3 == 0
    return "Fizz"
  elsif int % 5 == 0
    return "Buzz"
  elsif int % 15 == 15
    return "FizzBuzz"
  else
  end
end
```

Comment: Hint: Why are you expecting mod of number with 15 to be 15? Also, why return early? What happens when number is 30?

Comment: Hint: Consider order of operations. Also, remember in Ruby that `return` is implicit, you can omit them all here. You'll also want your `else` condition to contain `int`. What does `15 % 15` return when using a tool like `irb` for testing?

Comment: else needs to return nil my test is actually passing in that regard i need elsif to return a number divisible by 3 and 5 which i know is 15 i just didnt know how to get it i'm still trying to understand % i will play around in irb thank you

Comment: the ruby modulus is pretty easy once you remember `%` returns the REMAINDER of one number divided by another. so the the return of `5 % 3` is going to be `2` since 5 divided by 3 is 1, with a remainder of 2. The answer below gives you the rest ;) Enjoy Ruby, it's pretty sweet!

Answer (score 3):

So for conditionals, ruby evaluate the `if`, then the `elsif`, and finally the `else` in order. If anything condition evaluates to true, then the rest of the conditions are ignored.

```
def fizzbuzz(int)
  if int % 3 == 0
    return "Fizz"
  elsif int % 5 == 0
    return "Buzz"
  elsif int % 15 == 15
    return "FizzBuzz"
  else
  end
end
```

So let's look at a few examples based on your current code.

Say `int = 3`
We go to `if int % 3 == 0`, which is true, so the code return "Fizz" and nothing below that is evaluated.

Say `int = 5`, 
`int % 3 == 0` is false, we move onto the first elsif.
`int % 5 == 0` is true, we return "Buzz"

Now let's look at 15,
`int % 3 == 0` is true, so the code will return "Fizz" and ignores everything else, even if there are more conditions that will evaluate to be true after the if statement.

The order here is very important. You will want to check if `int % 15 == 0` first, then move onto `% 3` and `% 5`.